# Android: What does return createFromPath method, if the image does not exsist?

Tags: android, view, imageview

If I have to set image in the ImageView, taken form my sdcard, I use the following code:

```
 Drawable c = Drawable.createFromPath(imgPath);     
 if(c!=null)
    imageView.setImageResource(c);
```

I would know if a existence control for the file is required. What does return the method createFromPath, if the image does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java#Drawable.createFromPath%28java.lang.String%29) of `Drawable`:

```
 return null;
```

It will also return null, if you put null as input parameter.